# Connecting Veritas Backup Exec to a Synology Disk Station (NAS)?

Tags: backup, nas, unc

I am having trouble connecting our software "Veritas Backup Exec" to our network disk, a Synology Disk Station (NAS). Veritas is running on a Windows Server.

It will not except the UNC Path (Server \Share)

\ServerName\ShareName

When I enter these and hit return, it goes through a long validation process and then reports back invalid

Yet, I can enter these in Windows Explorer, or web browser and easily see the drive.

Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: What are you using to authenticate between the two systems.  Veritas runs on Linux, Synology is Linux’ish.  However, they are two systems, with their own permissions.  Making some assumptions since detailed information wasn’t provided.

Comment: It is running on a Windows Server. I have edited the question to reflect that

Comment: You are running Windows Server but how do you authenticate across platforms?

Comment: There is nothing in the documents of Backup Exec that states the need for this. Nor is the invalid path message indicative of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's an old question, 
Backup exec tries to connect to your synology share using the credentials of the Backup Exec Service! at the windows machine. 
You will have to set the BE Service to run as a user and give that user permissions at the synology side. 
Here I let BE run as DOMAIN\Backup user, joined the synology into the Windows Domain and gave DOMAIN\Backup full access to the shared folder at the synology.

*My Problem is, that obviously Backupexec kills sometimes the permissions at synology, so the backup is unable to write, grrr*

Hope this helps someone